# JavaFX ListView select items from two lists

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8, user-input

With one ListView, it is possible to select multiple items from it, with the line:

```
listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

Then retrieve the items selected with:

```
selectedItems =  listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
```

However, I have two ListViews (`listView` and `listView2`) in one window. Is there any way to select items across both these lists (by the user holding down `Ctrl` and selecting items)?

**Edit to clarify**:
For example, I want to be able to select items 1, 4, 5, and 6, then press `Delete`. I can hold down `Ctrl` and select 4, 5, and 6 from `list1`, then select 1 from `list2`. However, if I then change my mind, and actually want to just select 8, so **I release `Ctrl` and select 8, then everything in `list2` should be deselected**.

[image: Screenshot of two populated lists and a button]

Comment: That's the default behaviour. You'll get 2 lists not one, but adding them together shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a listener, that would check if `Ctrl` was being held down when the user changed what list they were selecting items from:

```
boolean controlIsDepressed = false;

list1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
    (observable) -> {
                Scene scene = list1.getScene();
                scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
                    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.CONTROL) {
                        controlIsDepressed = true;
                    }
                });
                scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
                    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.CONTROL) {
                        controlIsDepressed = false;
                    }
                });
                // Clear the other list if Ctrl is not being held down
                if (!controlIsDepressed) list2.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            });
```

And then similar for `list2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom implementation of the [`SelectionModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html) which you'd need to share between both lists and in which implement the selection constraints.

However I doubt you need this, if you have two lists with two selection models, use some selection listener and query both lists my impression is that you have already what you need.